# Section Heading for LaTeX Beamer Export - Using LaTeX Heading Optional Argument

Tags: org-mode, latex, beamer

I'm working on a presentation by exporting from org-mode to LaTeX beamer and finding need of using a section header with optional argument - this is due to the long name of my sections causing issues in the navigation bar at the top.

If you want to look at a how things look on the LaTeX end, a question was asked with images here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/530999/24238

The format in latex is (formed from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/531000/24238):

```latex
\section[Short Heading]{Reeeeallly Loooooong Heeeeaaaddding}
```

Is it possible to get this working through org-mode by some means? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/21615175/2777074 ?

Comment: That looks like it should work! Will give it a shot.

Comment: That seems to work great! If you want to post something in an answer based on it - feel free to do so and I'll accept it.

Comment: Please write a self-answer. I'm not an emacs users and don't want to post an answer which I did not test myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment by samcarter, a similar question was asked on Stack Overflow with the answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/21615175/2777074

As of org-mode 8.0, you can use the `ALT_TITLE` property into the property drawer of the section to specify an alternate title that will get exported into the correct optional field of the section. So in this case it would look like...

```
* Reeeeallly Loooooong Heeeeaaaddding
:PROPERTIES:
:ALT_TITLE: Short Heading
:END:
```

Thanks to samcarter for forwarding me to the correct solution!